# Problem with using the Joined option of ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting the first and the last column.

[DownloadData](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq6xsfyn2hq4g58/LSA_RTHETA2-5_m0.dat?dl=0)

When I use `ListPlot`, I have a problem with `Joined`.

```
ListPlot[{4/10*#[[1]], -4/10*#[[3]]} & /@ rtheta25m0, 
  PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Without `Joined` I get:

[image]

Why this is happening?

Comment: Values of the abscissa in your data are not in ascending order. Try `ListPlot[SortBy[First][yourCurrentArguments], yourOptions]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the x-values of your data are not in order. If we look at just the x-values by themselves, they should form a straight line.

```
newdat = {4/10*#[[1]], -4/10*#[[3]]}&/@rtheta25m0;
ListLinePlot[
  newdat[[All, 1]]
]
```

[image: X-values plot.]

You can fix this by sorting your data:

```
ListPlot[
  Sort[newdat],
  Joined -> True
]
```

This happens because `ListPlot` will join the data points in the order you provide them.